# Symfony 4 easy admin how to create common action?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, easyadmin

How to create common action like 'new' which will be do one action, for example send ajax request for get some kind of information.
I'm trying add action via config/packages/easy_admin.yaml

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Users:    
      list:
        actions:
          - { name: 'refresh', label: 'Refresh', icon: 'sync' }
```

But it's add 'refresh' link for each row in my list.

I will be grateful for example or link on information.

Comment: Your question is very unclear... Please edit it with specific information on what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not supported natively for now.

https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1400

You have to override the default list template to add your custom buttons:

```
{# /templates/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/default/list.html.twig #}

{% extends '@!EasyAdmin/default/list.html.twig' %}

{% block global_actions %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {# Add your code here, for example a button on the 'Users' list #}
    {% if _entity_config.name == "Users" %}
        <div class="button-action">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Refresh</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```